# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS no sound devices after every reboot and after executing pulseaudio -D there are now sources but still no sound. Help please?

Tags: sound

After installing my current version of ubuntu, I had no issues for months until I tried mounting two drives using fstab. I was able to do so but there was no sound after changing the fstab file. So, I erased my edited file to restore it back to the original file and ever since then I have still had the issue of no sound devices in the sound settings. I have executed pulseaudio -D which restores the audio sources but doesn't restore sound. I am connected to an acer r240hy bidx 23.8-inch ips hdmi dvi vga (1920 x 1080) widescreen monitor and I was using the headphone jack at the back for audio which worked fine fresh off install of ubuntu 16.04 LTS but now does not work. No video card, no audio card; just stock intel motherboard, Intel® Core™ i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz × 8 , Intel® Ivybridge Desktop Graphics. I have some knowledge around terminal and know how to execute commands well so if you need any information to help solve this issue, I'll gladly run the commands to get that info. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: Adding to the fstab, even wrong entries, has nothing to do with sound.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that much since nothing changed after switching back to the original file. Just letting the forum know what I was doing when I first noticed the issue.